# Bootstrap Modal before form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm new to Modals, I have a Form and when the user clicks submit, It will show a Modal confirming if the user wants to submit, the modal also contains the user input from the form fields. I searched all over the internet but can't find the right one on my needs. And all I see is that they tag the click event to open modal on a  a link. i have a input type submit. Can you give examples or ideas? Thanks! Here's my sample form.

```
<form role="form" id="formfield" action="inc/Controller/OperatorController.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_form" /> 

       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Last Name</label><span class="label label-danger">*required</span>
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lastname" id="lastname">
       </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label><span class="label label-danger">*required</span>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname" id="firstname">
       </div>

  <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-default" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete?"/>
  <input type="button" name="btn" value="Reset" onclick="window.location='fillup.php'" class="btn btn-default" data-modal-type="confirm"/>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried using the bootstrap modal and jQuery?

Comment: I am trying this one. http://www.bootply.com/59864 and I want to implement it to mine. Can you help me out?

Comment: have your tried just open up a modal box using the bootstrap platform? Use this documentation: [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

So if I get it right, on click of a button, you want to open up a modal that lists the values entered by the users followed by submitting it.

For this, you first change your `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"` and add `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit"` so that the modal gets triggered when you click on it:

```
<input type="button" name="btn" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Next, the modal dialog:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Confirm Submit
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to submit the following details?

                <!-- We display the details entered by the user here -->
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <td id="lname"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <td id="fname"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a href="#" id="submit" class="btn btn-success success">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, a little bit of jQuery:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function() {
     /* when the button in the form, display the entered values in the modal */
     $('#lname').text($('#lastname').val());
     $('#fname').text($('#firstname').val());
});

$('#submit').click(function(){
     /* when the submit button in the modal is clicked, submit the form */
    alert('submitting');
    $('#formfield').submit();
});
```

You haven't specified what the function `validateForm()` does, but based on this you should restrict your form from being submitted. Or you can run that function on the form's button `#submitBtn` click and then load the modal after the validations have been checked.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0gct8qd8/)**

Comment: Hi Thank you so much this what I exactly need. :) But I have problem, when I change the <input type="submit" to <input type="button" I cannot get the data on the fields, I'm getting blank data.

Comment: @user3651491 Where is it that you are getting the blank data? If this has to do with your validations, you should run the `validateForm()` when the button is clicked, if the validations are met only then load the modal.

Comment: Great answer. But please don't use .html() to output the values. Use .text instead. The user would not expect to be able to enter html in the field. On the other hand, the user would be missing his input if he actually enters some tags, that the browser does not understand.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for explaining why. Corrected.

Comment: in situation when there is more than one form and want to show confirmation modal for every form submission *(this could be form, or list with delete action)*, then this method will fail, because inside `$('#submit').click` handler, no information is about which form to submit.

Comment: nice.but $('#formid').submit(); is not working for me .help

Comment: @rahulsingh can you make a jsfiddle of your problem?

Comment: @Can Has Kittenz thanks but the problem was with submit button id as i renamed id of the button to  something else its working like champ

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz what if i have two buttons that trigger the modal.  Once that is for 'save and continue' the other for 'save and close' . since they are no long submit buttons and being passed to the controller, i don't know what button the user originally pressed.  is there any way to persist that information?

Comment: @user1161137 you can assign different name for each button, eg. `<input type="button" name="saveContinueBtn"> <input type="button" name="saveCloseBtn">` Then you can identify which button was clicked using the name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser default prompt window.
Instead of basic `<input type="submit" (...) >` try:

```
<button onClick="if(confirm(\'are you sure ?\')){ this.form.submit() }">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form button[type="submit"]').on('click', function () {
   $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to solve, only create an hidden submit:

```
<button id="submitCadastro" type="button">ENVIAR</button>
<input type="submit" id="submitCadastroHidden" style="display: none;" >
```

with jQuery you click the submit:

```
$("#submitCadastro").click(function(){
    if($("#checkDocumentos").prop("checked") == false){
        //alert("Aceite os termos e condições primeiro!.");
        $("#modalERROR").modal("show");
    }else{
        //$("#formCadastro").submit();
        $("#submitCadastroHidden").click();                     
    }
});
```

Comment: Me ajudou.... Quando tentava enviar através do botão no modal dava erro pois não enviava os dados do form... dessa forma resolveu o problema, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some of the answers were not triggering the HTML5 `required` attribute (as stuff was being executed on the action of *clicking* rather than the action of *form send*, causing to bypass it when the inputs were empty):

1. Have a `<form id='xform'></form>` with some inputs with the required attribute and place a `<input type='submit'>` at the end.
2. A confirmation input where typing "ok" is expected `<input type='text' name='xconf' value='' required>`
3. Add a **modal_1_confirm** to your html (to confirm the form of sending).
4. (on modal_1_confirm) add the **id** `modal_1_accept` to the accept button.
5. Add a second **modal_2_errMsg** to your html (to display form validation errors).
6. (on modal_2_errMsg) add the **id** `modal_2_accept` to the accept button.
7. (on modal_2_errMsg) add the **id** `m2_Txt` to the displayed text holder.
8. The JS to intercept before the form is sent:

   ```
   $("#xform").submit(function(e){
       var msg, conf, preventSend;

       if($("#xform").attr("data-send")!=="ready"){
           msg="Error."; //default error msg
           preventSend=false;

           conf=$("[name='xconf']").val().toLowerCase().replace(/^"|"$/g, "");

           if(conf===""){
               msg="The field is empty.";
               preventSend=true;
           }else if(conf!=="ok"){
               msg="You didn't write \"ok\" correctly.";
               preventSend=true;
           }

           if(preventSend){ //validation failed, show the error
               $("#m2_Txt").html(msg); //displayed text on modal_2_errMsg
               $("#modal_2_errMsg").modal("show");
           }else{ //validation passed, now let's confirm the action
               $("#modal_1_confirm").modal("show");
           }

           e.preventDefault();
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

`9. Also some stuff when clicking the Buttons from the modals:

```
$("#modal_1_accept").click(function(){
    $("#modal_1_confirm").modal("hide");
    $("#xform").attr("data-send", "ready").submit();
});

$("#modal_2_accept").click(function(){
    $("#modal_2_errMsg").modal("hide");
});
```

**Important Note:** So just be careful if you add an extra way to show the modal, as simply clicking the accept button `$("#modal_1_accept")` will assume the validation passed and it will add the `"ready"` attribute:

- The reasoning for this is that `$("#modal_1_confirm").modal("show");` is shown *only* when it passed
  the validation, so clicking `$("#modal_1_accept")` should be
  unreachable without first getting the form validated.