# Submit button in Bootstrap form doesn't react on enter key

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, input, submit, bootstrap-modal

I have following Bootsrap form:

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×,
      </span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Datei speichern
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Gib einen Dateinamen ein
    </p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="input-label" for="project-bar-input">
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project-bar-input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="modal-cancel btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="modal-action btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Speichern
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try to catch an ENTER key event with

```
$( ".modal-content" ).find( "input#submit" ).click( function() {
    // submit
});
```

After reading:

> [Submit button not working in Bootstrap form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314587/submit-button-not-working-in-bootstrap-form)

But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Try $('form').on('submit' ,   as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517642/open-bootstrap-modal-when-enter-pressed-on-form/63517840#63517840

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.modal-content').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
      //dosomething
      alert('Enter pressed');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×,
      </span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Datei speichern
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Gib einen Dateinamen ein
    </p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="input-label" for="project-bar-input">
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project-bar-input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="modal-cancel btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="modal-action btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Speichern
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```