# Submit Button is not working In Razor asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `ViewModel`, Controller and View like below:

```
public class H2HViewModel
{
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public byte TransferMethod { get; set; }
    public string ListOfSelectedBatchID { get; set; }    
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Create(H2HViewModel model)
 {
   var detailPayments = db.Payments.Where(x => x.Status == 2).ToList();
   foreach (Payment detail in detailPayments)
   {
       detail.PaymentStatus = 4; 
       detail.EffectiveDate = model.EffectiveDate;
       detail.TransferMethod = model.TransferMethod.ToString();
   }
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "User");
 }
```

View

```
@model EPayment.Data.ViewModels.H2HViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, new { @class = "form-control dtpicker" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TransferMethod, "AB", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form -control" } }) AB
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TransferMethod, "BC", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form -control" } }) BC
          
    </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
}
```

When I click the submit button nothing happens,
I made a breakpoints on `ActionResult`'s create to debug it, but nothing happened.

I refer to this [stackoverflow.com/questions/16443927](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443927/submit-button-is-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc), and have done it but it didn't work, any idea?

Comment: you don't have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on your post method, and your post method doesn't return any data!

Comment: sory I missed it, I have updated the code above @LazZiya

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying where to post that form... `Html.BeginForm` can take [several parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). You should be specifying the `ActionName` and `ControllerName`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
```

*Note: "Controller" will be the name of your controller.*

Comment: @chaeusangchen can you post the rest of your HTML? Your model is probably not deserializing properly. What type of response do you get back?

Comment: Hi @maxshuty, I have updated my html in the code above. 
I did not get any response